# Creating custom field to via Metadata api, and adding it to layout

Tags: metadata, custom-metadata

I added a field via Metadata Api to the Lead. It is not exposed via API due to the Field Accessibility. 
Since I am on Professional Edition, I have to control the Accessibility / Field Visibility through the Page Layout.

In our Org, we are also using 2 different Object Types for Leads. I fetched the Layout for Lead ("Lead-Lead Layout") as well as for one of the object types ("Lead-Caterer Layout") and tried to add the Field to those Layouts.
However, whenever I want to add them (programmatically), I get the message

```
{ 
  message: 'In Field: field - no CusotmField named Lead.Email_History__c found', 
  statusCode: 'INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY' 
}
```

The field does in fact exist, though.